# Remove posts permalink (href)

Tags: wordpress, href, permalinks

I am trying to figure out a way to remove permalink's from posts with the category 'nolink'. I have tried a few java script attempts - but have not managed to get it to work.

```
<?php 
query_posts( 'tag=Client-list' );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<ul class="client-thumb-wrap">';
        echo '<a href="';
            the_permalink();
        echo '">';
            echo '<li class="'; 
                $category = get_the_category( $custompost );
                echo $category[0]->cat_name ;
                    echo ' ';
                echo $category[1]->cat_name ;
                    echo ' ';
                echo $category[2]->cat_name ;
                    echo ' ';
                echo $category[3]->cat_name ;
            echo '">';

            echo '<img src="';
            the_field('client_logo');
            echo '">';
        echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`has_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) allows you to check if a post has a specific term assigned (or not), try:

```
$href = ( has_term( 'nolink', 'category' ) ) ? '#' : get_permalink();
echo '<a href="' . $href . '">';
```

Comment: Brilliant that has worked, but because of the # it is still a link to the current page, id it possible to remove the a href totally from those posts?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to do the operation twice, to remove the closing `</a>` as well. In that case, you should move the html into the conditional check: `$href = ( has_term( 'nolink', 'category' ) ) ? '' : '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';`

Comment: Sorry mu apologies for making you doubt your code. It has worked!